# Resources not available after update to vaadin 21.0.9

Tags: vaadin

All my resources (images, fonts) below **resources/META-INF/resources** are not rendered anymore since my update from Vaadin 21.0.1 to 21.0.9

Works still well from the IDE, but not after built normally.

When trying to address a resource directly by entering its URL in the browser, I get redirected to login.

Already tried to update Springboot version used, but did not help.

Comment: 21.0.9 is no longer supported. Can you try to update to 22.0.2 and check if the problem persists?

Comment: update fixed the problem

Comment: Great! Either add this as the answer or delete the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update fixed problem as proposed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. These rules apply even when answering your own question. Note that comments can be deleted at any time, for any reason. If this answer depends on comments, please incorporate them into the answer so it makes sense as a standalone answer.